# Selecting an entire line from TextArea on mouse click

Tags: javafx, textarea

I am using JavaFX for my application. In my application I have a button,on click on that button should display the results on textarea, that I am able to do. Now I would like to select the entire line on click from the text area. But The code which I have written is able to select only the value which I click which means like only word on which I have clicked. Please suggest me to modify this.

```
@FXML
public void find_btn_action(ActionEvent event) throws MWException
{

      double[] peaks= {1.2,5.6,8.0,9.0};
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(peaks.length);
      for(int i= 0; i < peaks.length ; i++)
     {
       result[i] = peaks[i];
       sb.append(result[i]+"\n");
   }

      auto.setText(sb.toString());  
      auto.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event arg0)
        {
            selectedVal = auto.getSelectedText();
            System.out.println("selected text:"+ selectedVal);

        }
    });

  }
```

Comment: a) Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.
b) unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: Sorry I'll follow the java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

In your mouse click listener check, if the click was inside the content area and if this is the case, use the caret position to determine the next/previous line break in the `TextArea`'s text and select this range:

```
textArea.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
    if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {

        // check, if click was inside the content area
        Node n = evt.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode();
        while (n != textArea) {
            if (n.getStyleClass().contains("content")) {
                // find previous/next line break
                int caretPosition = textArea.getCaretPosition();
                String text = textArea.getText();
                int lineBreak1 = text.lastIndexOf('\n', caretPosition - 1);
                int lineBreak2 = text.indexOf('\n', caretPosition);
                if (lineBreak2 < 0) {
                    // if no more line breaks are found, select to end of text
                    lineBreak2 = text.length();
                }

                textArea.selectRange(lineBreak1, lineBreak2);
                evt.consume();
                break;
            }
            n = n.getParent();
        }
    }
});
```